# SQL - Using LIKE with placeholder with AND & OR operators

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I am trying to use the LIKE operator along with wildcards to check for similar matches in 2 columns in each of the [Food] and [Drinks] table.

The below is my solution, but it will not run. Code below: (I have left a gap in the middle for reading purposes).

```
" SELECT DISTINCT r.restname"
    + " FROM restaurants r"
    + " JOIN food f ON f.restid = r.restid"
    + " JOIN drinks d ON d.restid = r.restid"

    + " WHERE f.foodcategory LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')" 
    + " OR f.foodname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')"
    + " AND d.drinkname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')" 
    + " OR d.drinkvariety LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')");
```

Comment: (... OR  ...) AND ( ... OR ...)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"it will not run"*? Do you get an error?

Comment: Hi, it is part of a Java Web application, so a standard "HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException" is the error

Comment: That doesn't sound like it is anything to do with the SQL. Can you  post your Java code that is calling this SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Add your words to ' ? ' and check.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT r.restname
    FROM restaurants r
    JOIN food f ON f.restid = r.restid
    JOIN drinks d ON d.restid = r.restid 
    WHERE (f.foodcategory LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')" OR
    f.foodname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')) 
    AND (d.drinkname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR
    d.drinkvariety LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `exists` instead -- as I suggested in an earlier question.

But your problem is the lack of parentheses:

```
WHERE (f.foodcategory LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')" OR
       f.foodname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
      ) AND
      (d.drinkname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR
       d.drinkvariety LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
      )
```